# Imported jar compiles perfectly but gives a run time error

Tags: java, android-studio, jar, compilation

I am building my project using 4 external jars. I have added the libraries in my project and I can see them in gradle.build file also.

When I do a gradle sync it compiles the code perfectly but as soon as I launch, it gives me an error

```
Cannot find symbol <classname from the imported jar>
```

This is happening with only one jar and all other are working fine.

**Note**: The jar does contain that file.

I want to ask if it compiles properly then why is it giving me an error at the time of launch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem. The jars that I was using were not compatible with minimum android api level 16 so I changed that to a later version.

The strange thing was that I got this error only when I configured it as a maven repository. Also, if you face the same problem when your jar mismatches the minimum sdk level you can use

```
tools:overrideLibrary
```

in AndroidManifest.xml..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the jar is on the classpath at compile time but not run time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my concern is that why do other 3 jars are not giving me that error.

Comment: Without more info it's difficult to answer that question.  Perhaps your program has not yet tried to access classes in any of those 3 other jars yet.  Ultimately class not found errors are caused by the fact that there is no .class file available in any of the locations specified on your class path.  Do you know what the class path the JVM is being invoked with actually is?  You could write a test program that just prints out the value of the java system property "java.class.path".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am using other three jars in classes and those are working fine. The only thing now that I am suspecting now is the jar it self. May be it is corrupted.